# How to create a pivot table with unique seed data in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following **Movies** table and **Actors** table with a pivot table of **Movie_Actor**.

[image: Entity Relationship Diagram Example (UML Notation)]

How do I create a pivot table **Movie_Actor** pivot table and provide **many-to-many** relationship with Eloquent and seed the **Movie_Actor** table with **unique** faker data between the Movies and Actors.
 For example, 1 movie has many actors and Actors have many movies. If there are 20 movies and 80 Actors how can I build Faker data for the Movie_Actor.

ps. I have already provided [Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) content for Movies and Actors
pps. I have search StackOverflow for other answers still struggling with this concept
ppps. I have watched [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com) videos and [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLpzy7FIRqpGD0kxI48v8QEVVZd744Phi4) series which cover this topic.
pppps. I know Laravel has [generators](https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended) which help create pivot tables
ppppps. I have tried to use the Laravel Documentation on [Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: You say you checked the docs but your example is relatively straightforward and covered in detail here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: @lufc No, that documentation does not cover seeding unique data for a pivot table.

See modifiers under the readme of this page: https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker

Comment: Your first two questions are covered on that page. Your last is covered here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-seed-a-pivot-table-in-laravel